# Unable to figure out which partition to uninstall Ubuntu from Windows laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

A little under a decade my friend installed Ubuntu with a flash drive onto my Windows laptop as dual-boot. Now I want to uninstall it but I'm having a hard time figuring out which partition is the correct Linux partition.

All input much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

[image: DISK MANAGEMENT and Command Prompt]

[image]

Comment: Now, you might actually need LOCAL help with this. One way to possible figure out the situation; download an Ubuntu ISO and create a boot media from it (e.g. on an USB-stick). Boot it in "Try Ubuntu"-mode and use the tools in there, e.g. "gparted", to check the actual situation - i.e. listing linux partitions on the disk (which Windows apparently is not capable to do).

Comment: @Hannu makes a good suggestion. In “Try Ubuntu” mode you will be able to confirm which partition is for Linux. It will probably be formatted as “ext4” which is visible in the GParted app. However if there is a Linux partition there it is the 58GB partition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: Gparted is a great idea, and I'm pretty sure that running Gparted (or other partition manager) from your currently installed Ubuntu would be easier than making a bootable disk.

Comment: @hoatzin The partition you boot from is locked in gparted. You can't modify the boot and swap partitions while Ubuntu is running and using them. That's why you need a bootable disk.

Comment: @user68186 True.  I was thinking that "hobo" just needed to confirm the Linux partition.  But, that will do them no good if they can't actually wipe it.  Good point.

Comment: I think once identified the partition can be deleted from Windows Disk Management and subsequently reused for a new Windows partition or a resizing exercise. It looks like partition 6 is the one but best to confirm in the way that has been described